# Amount of Subscribers in Entry Audience in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

as there are always separate ways to come to the same goal in the Marketing Cloud, I wonder about this scenario.

We have lets say 500.000 subscriber I want to contact. Does anything speak against sending Emails to this amount via Journey Builder? Performance wise and from a view of experience and best practice?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Journey Builder is a 1:1 customer journey automation.
If your requirement is just to send bulk email to 500,000 contacts , you need to use guided send or an automation. Journey Builder will take time to evaluate contacts within entry source and inject them into journey. This happens in a batch and may depend on server resources as well.

In short, JB is not designed to be a bulk email send tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IN this case it would be a two step Journey. Meaning after Sending, there should be an update on if the email was clicked and than send a second message. Do you have any ideas about the sizes of the batches, so that it could be roughly estimated how long it would take for 500.000 contacts? And from what size would you speak from a buld send out? Regards

Comment: @UnaisKomath is correct. JB is not designed for this. This would likely be better as 2 automations. 1 with your initial guided send and a second using a SQL query to gather those that clicked the link and then send another message.